# What is the whistling in the restroom about in "My Name is Nobody"?

Tags: plot-explanation, my-name-is-nobody

In the 1973 "My Name is Nobody" (with Terence Hill), there is a scene where Nobody and the driver of a train are in a restroom, facing each other. The driver obviously has problems "letting go". Nobody does make some whistling sounds, and with a face of utter bliss, the train driver finally relieves himself.

I never "got" that scene. I mean, the facial expressions are funny as heck, but...

- why has the driver problems "letting go" in the first place?
- why does another person *whistling* help him?

Is this a scene that's just "not realistic" and there only for some slapstick? Or is there something involved I am just not aware of, like a medical condition etc.?

Comment: Yes, I know, a short scene in a 40-year-old movie. (Damn... it's been *that* long?) But I *always* ask myself this, to the point where it is spoiling my fun a bit whenever I am watching this old favourite of mine...

Comment: [Like Once upon a Time in the West, it’s a meta western: a western about the West, and about the Western. Alternating ‘serious’ sequences in the tradition of the classic Hollywood western, with swift action from the Dollar movies and parodist slapstick in the Trinity tradition, it reflects the development and degeneration of the genre.](http://www.spaghetti-western.net/index.php/My_Name_is_Nobody_Review)

Comment: Well ... I don't know if this qualify for an answer but .. according to researcher Professor Anna-Lena Hellström recent studies on Vietnamese babies, there seems to be a connection between the whistling and the "letting go" :) [Link](http://www.medicaldaily.com/whistling-could-help-babies-get-potty-trained-and-out-diapers-just-9-months-244398)

Comment: Haven't seen the movie, but I can say that it's sometimes referred to as a "shy bladder".  Personally, when I go to a stadium-type event where there are dozens of people queued up to a urinal, I have to go into a stall.  Just can't do it with 30 people staring at me.  Anyway, as far as the whistling, it'd be funny if the guy was whistling "Moon River", "Singing In The Rain" or something that has to do with water, as they say the sound or thought of water helps you relax and "let go".